# How to get amount into parts with nearest 100

Tags: c#

I am using below code to divide amount into parts

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DistributeInteger(double total, int divider)
{
    if (divider == 0)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        double rest = total % divider;
        double result = total / (double)divider;

        for (int i = 0; i < divider; i++)
        {
            if (rest-- > 0)
                yield return (int)Math.Ceiling(result);
            else
                yield return (int)Math.Floor(result);
        }
    }
}
```

and using it as follows

```
var test = DistributeInteger(5000, 4).ToList();
```

above code returning me.

```
1250
1250
1250
1250
```

(All four part sum = 5000)

but i need it as nearest 100 of each part like

```
1300
1300
1300
1100
```

If I pass

```
var test = DistributeInteger(5219, 5).ToList();
```

then it is returning

```
1044
1044
1044
1044
1043
```

(All five part sum = 5219)
but it should be

```
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
219
```

if amount 1 to 100 for example 89 then it will return same amount which is 89,

I am trying it from morning but no luck.
as well as i checked may codes from net but it is giving only solution to get nearest 100 value of a given no.

Comment: for 5219, 5 shouldn't it returns `1100 
1100 
1100 
1100 
819 ` ?

Comment: divide total by 100, then by diveder, then get ceil, then multiply it by 100 ... now first diveider - 1 elements would be this number ... and last would be total - sum of the rest

Comment: also why it has 4 elements for divider 4 and 6 elements for divider 5 ?

Comment: @Selvin i need 4 elements for divider 4 becouse 1300+1300+1300+1100 = 5000, and 6 elements for divider 5 is becouse 1000 * 5 + 219 = 5219

Comment: i want to get equal part amount nearest to 100 so parts will different on divider

Comment: hehe ... *i need 4 elements for divider 4 becouse 1300+1300+1300+1100 = 5000, and 6 elements for divider 5 is becouse 1000 * 5 + 219 = 5219* it doesnt make sens - why not 4*1100 + 819 ? it would have sens as you would get the number of elemnts equal to the divider ...

Comment: @Selvin 5219, 5 will be rounded to 5220 and it will give 1100 1100 1100 1100 820

Comment: its a loan amount which want to divide as per user requirement. its depend on user how he divide, he can take only 1 month also as per his need

Comment: @Selvin, I got your point, sorry for this, because i am florescent tube light, which light a little slow, you are correct, if divider is 5 and if parts can not fits in 5 then next other month can be added, may be 6 or 7 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DistributeInteger(double total, int divider)
{
    int part = 100 * ((int)(50 + total / divider) / 100);

    if (part == 0)
    {
        yield return (int)total;
        yield break;
    }

    double runningTotal = 0;

    while (runningTotal <= (total - part))
    {
        yield return part;
        runningTotal += part;
    }

    if (runningTotal < total)
        yield return (int) (total - runningTotal);
}
```

(Note: Error handling omitted for brevity.)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DistributeInteger(double total, int divider)
{
    // get increment to the nearest hundred
    var increment = (int) Math.Round(total/ 100 / divider, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 100;

    // make sure increment is non-zero
    if (increment == 0) increment = 100;

    var remainder = (int) total;

    // subtract increment while remainder is >= zero
    while (remainder >= increment){
        remainder -= increment;
        yield return increment;
    }

    // check if remainder is non-zero
    if (remainder > 0)
        yield return remainder;
}
```

**<strike>Now uses Ceiling</strike>**

**Seems to work with midpoint rounding away from zero**

Comment: it does't return `1300
1300
1300
1100` for 5000, 4 ... it returns 6 items(error in the question?) for 5219, 5

Comment: @Selvin Changed answer to use Ceiling instead, results should match OPs expectations

Comment: @Selvin Hmm, that didn't work either, try this version

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DistributeInteger(double total, int divider)
{
  if (divider == 0)
  {
    return null;
  }
  else
  {
    var parts = new List<int>();
    var singlePart = total / divider;
    singlePart = Math.Round(singlePart / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 100;
    while (total - singlePart > 0)
    {
      parts.Add((int)singlePart);
      total -= singlePart;
    }
    // Add remainnig value.
    parts.Add((int)total);
    return parts;
  }
}
```

It will work for second scenario only, for the first scenarion you'd need to use `Ceiling` function instead of `Round`.

Comment: it does't return 1300 1300 1300 1100 for 5000, 4 ... problem is with the question itself